# How does JavaBean search for attribute? Does it look at just name or scope as well?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, attributes, javabeans

Say I have class Person:

```
package com.example;

public class Person {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Person() {
    }

}
```

And I use Servlet called `MyServlet` to create Person object inside request's scope as attribute:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Person p1 = new Person("Evan");
        req.setAttribute("person", p1);

        RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("/result.jsp");
        view.forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Finally, JSP gets *forwarded* request and tries to print attribute. Notice how I purposely set `scope="application"` and not `scope="request"` as opposed to where attribute is located:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html><body>

<jsp:useBean id="person" class="com.example.Person" scope="application"/>
Welcome <jsp:getProperty name="person" property="name"/>

</body></html>
```

I expected that JSP wouldn't find attribute as I explicitly told it to "search" for attributes located in **application's scope** and my attribute is located at **request's scope**. To my surprise, I get printed message `Hello Evan`, meaning it somehow found it. Can someone explain me how?

I was also reading Head First Servlets and JSP, where I came across this (page 350). This picture (line 3) shows how it searches for attribute at REQUEST_SCOPE:
[image]

So can someone really help me figure out how did it find my attribute when it is searching for "person" **just inside request's scope**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of [`<jsp:getProperty>`](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jsp-2_3-mrel2-eval-spec/JSP2.3MR.pdf?AuthParam=1609268254_4c2b6dbbea74d82d90a55910892919db#G12.1010449) says:

> The value of the `name` attribute in `jsp:setProperty` and `jsp:getProperty` will refer to an object that is obtained from the `pageContext` object through its `findAttribute` method.

The javadoc of [`findAttribute(String name)`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jspapi/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#findAttribute-java.lang.String-) says:

> Searches for the named attribute in page, request, session (if valid), and application scope(s) in order and returns the value associated or null.

Your `<jsp:useBean>` likely created a new instance using the default constructor, and assigned it to the application scope, but `<jsp:getProperty>` retrieved the value from the instance found a request scope, because it looked there first.

I'd recommend not using `<jsp:getProperty>`, and instead just use EL.

With EL you would write `${person.name}`. To force a specific scope, you can prefix with:

- `pageScope.`
- `requestScope.`
- `sessionScope.`
- `applicationScope.`

E.g. `${applicationScope.person.name}` should be `null`, since the application-scope instance was created with the default constructor.

*Note:* When writing text into an HTML document, and the text originated from a user, you should always escape it. Use `<c:out value="${person.name}"/>` to do that, after correctly adding the *JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library* (JSTL) to your project.

Comment: So what you wanted to say is that this picture used `findAttribute()` behind the scenes? And can you explain the part: *Your <jsp:useBean> likely created a new instance using the default constructor?* instance of what are you talking about? Instance of attribute or...

Comment: @Stefan "created a new instance using the **default constructor**". Constructors are used to create **objects**. So it means "new instance of the `Person` class, as named in the `class` attribute of the `<jsp:useBean>` tag.

Comment: Oh I see. But please tell me following. Isn't `<jsp:getProperty>`'s name attribute referencing to `<jsp:useBean>`'s ID attribute? So howcome can `getProperty()` use `findAttribute()` to look "somewhere else"? Shouldn't it strictly be "tied" to **single** Java bean? Meaning isn't `<jsp:useBean>` part of code responsible for finding actual "name", so howcome can `getProperty()` call `fndAttribute()`, when `getProperty()` just gets properties from given Java Bean? It is so confusing for me, sorry :(

Comment: @Stefan No, `<jsp:getProperty>` isn't specifically tied to `<jsp:useBean>`. If you remove `<jsp:useBean>`, the code will still print the person's name, because an attribute with name `person` exists (in request scope). It doesn't matter *how* the attribute was assigned, using `<jsp:useBean>` or in Java code, or in what scope. Actually, having multiple attributes of the same name defined in different scopes, is highly discouraged, since it's confusing, unless you specifically use it to e.g. have a global default value defined in *application* scope, then use *request* scope for overrides.